# How can I resize my ubuntu partition if ubuntu is the only system I can get into?

Tags: 13.04, partitioning, ram

I am using gparted to resize my partition. I would like to free up all of my memory and allocate this to ubuntu, but I can't mess with ubuntu's partition while it is in use. I can, for some reason, no longer get into my windows 8 OS because of an EFI error. I just installed ubuntu 13.04 so would it be easier to just re-install and have ubuntu install over everything else, or is there a way with gparted?

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ubuntu live and use Gparted there.

Comment: Umm... I would have dwelled a bit more in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

try using the gparted live disk: http://gparted.sourceforge.net/livecd.php
it's a easy to use live disk to partition/resize your hard drive.
I use it quite often and I've never run into (unsolvable) problems with it.